# zip.js : File format is not recognized, javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, client-side-scripting, zip.js

I am getting a zip file response from a HTTP GET request which contains two other files in it of extensions .log and .out. I am using zip.js to successfully read the data from the .log file but when I try to pass the text data, read from the .log file, as an argument to an event , I get the error :

"File Format is not recognized"

I am doing this on client-side javascript.

Here is my code :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var blobData = new Blob([this.response],{type : "application/zip"});
    zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(blobData), function(zipReader){
        zipReader.getEntries(function(entries){

                entries[1].getData(new zip.TextWriter(), function(text){
                        console.log(text);

                        this.Emit("dataReady", {
                            data : text});
                });
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this),this.onerror);
}.bind(this);

 xhr.open("GET","path/to/url/file.zip",true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/zip");
 xhr.responseType = 'blob';    
 xhr.send();
```

The error I am getting is:

File format is not recognized.

Please advice as I am using zip.js and reading a zip file response from an http request for the first time.Thanks!

Comment: which line exactly does the error point to?

Comment: The error points to zip.js, line no. 920 where the default error handling is used when using the createReader function

Comment: createReader : function(reader, callback, onerror) {
   onerror = onerror || onerror_default;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that you are using the correct `this` at this line

```
this.Emit("dataReady", { data : text});
```

I am not sure to where you are emitting the text but you may be calling Emit on the wrong object. If this is the case then please take a look at this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call and do something like to quickly test. Note, I notice that you are already binding "this"

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var _root = this;
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var blobData = new Blob([this.response],{type : "application/zip"});
    zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(blobData), function(zipReader){
        zipReader.getEntries(function(entries){

                entries[1].getData(new zip.TextWriter(), function(text){
                        console.log(text);

                        _root.Emit("dataReady", {
                            data : text});
                });
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this),this.onerror);
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: I treid that @nada, i am still getting the same error.

Comment: @arnavJJ have you found a solution?

Comment: nope, I am stuck. No matter what I do , I get the same error. I even tried making a File object of the response and passing it as a parameter to another function, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: @arnavJJ I really hate not being able to help someone. I would just like to make sure that I really understand. In the original code you posted, when you comment out the line this.Emit(...) you do not get the error right?

Comment: thats very helpful of you. yes, along with commenting out that line, I also need to remove the bind(this) statements. If I do all this, then there is no error

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere, so binding also causes the same problem? What function is this in? As in, where is var xhr = new XMLH....?

Comment: I am displaying a list on the page and on a specific list item click, this function executes for which the entire code I have pasted in my question

Comment: @arnavJJ ok, without seeing the actual code it is not easy for me understand how you are doing all of it so lets first try by by commenting out ALL of the code you posted in the question and just try this.Emit("dataReady", { data : "test"}); does it give what you expected?

Comment: Yes, I know but I cannot share the entire code. When I comment out the entire code and try emitting the event with "test" as arg, I do see what I expect, looks like we are making progress

Comment: @arnavJJ I understand. Ok, let's try the whole thing again now without all the binds. That is, remove all the binds from the code and do like I suggested in the answer, put var _root = this; outside the onload and swap _root for all the "this"

Comment: Earlier, when I was using it without the binds, I was getting the error : "this.Emit is undefined", but now no such error as well. Why do you think is it so?

Comment: @arnavJJ great!!!! I think the problem was in one of the binds. If you want to continue with using bind I think you can just try removing the binds one by one ti see which will work.